# Arduino due using a pushbutton

Tags: button, arduino

I'm trying to use some push buttons on my arduino due board, but it's not reading them right.
After doing some research I found out that I had to connect a resistor in the circuit.

However, the datasheet says you can use the build in pull-up resistor
but for me that still doesn't work. I used the following code;

```
void setup() {
    pinMode(22, INPUT);
    pinMode(23, INPUT);
    pinMode(24, INPUT);
    pinMode(25, INPUT);
    digitalWrite(22, HIGH); // pullup resistors
    digitalWrite(23, HIGH); // pullup resistors
    digitalWrite(24, HIGH); // pullup resistors
    digitalWrite(25, HIGH); // pullup resistors
}
```

and to check if the button is pressed:

```
if (digitalRead(22)) {
    // do code
}
```

the buttons are simply connected as follows:

```
+3.3V -> button -> pin 22
```

What might I have done wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to connect the other side of the button to ground, not 3.3 volts. You've already pulled the inputs `HIGH` (3.3 volts), so that's your steady state. When the button is pushed, your `digitalRead` will tell you `LOW`. Otherwise you can't detect it, as pushing the button doesn't change anything.